# OpenGL slower than Canvas

Tags: opengl, android, opengl-es, html-canvas

Up to 3 days ago I used a **Canvas** in a **SurfaceView** to do all the graphics operations but now I switched to **OpenGL** because my game went from **60FPS** to 30/45 with the increase of the sprites in some levels. However, I find myself disappointed because **OpenGL** now reaches around 40/50 FPS at all levels. Surely (I hope) I'm doing something wrong. How can I increase the performance at  stable **60FPS**? My game is pretty simple and I can not believe that it is impossible to reach them.

I use 2D sprite texture applied to a square for all the objects. I use a transparent GLSurfaceView, the real background is applied in a ImageView behind the GLSurfaceView.

Some code

```
    public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context);
        setZOrderOnTop(true);
        setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0);
        getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
        mRenderer = new ClearRenderer(getContext());
        setRenderer(mRenderer);
        setLongClickable(true);
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    public void onSurfaceCreated(final GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);

        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        gl.glDepthMask(false);

        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_ALPHA_TEST);
        gl.glAlphaFunc(GL10.GL_GREATER, 0);

        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
        gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_ONE, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION); 
        gl.glLoadIdentity(); 

        gl.glOrthof(0, width, height, 0, -1f, 1f);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        // Draw all the graphic object.
        for (byte i = 0; i < mGame.numberOfObjects(); i++){
            mGame.getObject(i).draw(gl);
        }

        // Disable the client state before leaving
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    }
```

mGame.getObject(i).draw(gl) is for all the objects like this:

```
    /* HERE there is always a translatef and scalef transformation and sometimes rotatef */

    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTexPointer[0]);

    // Point to our vertex buffer
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mVertexBuffer);
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mTextureBuffer);

    // Draw the vertices as triangle strip
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, mVertices.length / 3);
```

**EDIT:**

After some test it seems to be due to the transparent GLSurfaceView. If I delete this line of code:

```
    setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0);
```

the background becomes all black but I reach 60 fps. What can I do?

Comment: Having a transparent GLSurfaceView does sound like it might be a problem in a browser.

As for your edit, surely you require a depth buffer bitcount to be set via the 5th parameter of setEGLConfigChooser? 16 being an acceptable value, for instance.

Comment: I already tried to change it to 16 or 24 but nothing changes.

Comment: While it's unlikely the problem you're hitting just now, note that drawing each individual sprite is inefficient.  Canvas may be doing some _batching_ optimizations behind the scenes, which you will need to do yourself with OpenGL.  For many simpler sprite-based games, you need only a single _texture atlas_ (and one bind) and a single draw call for all sprites.

Comment: I'm very interested to this comment, can you link me a site that explores the question? Anyways thank you for the tip.

Comment: @VanDir have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9671202/1326821) answer (and it's question) for a very quick description of how to do a texture atlas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using an ImageView and transparent GLSurfaceView you should instead render your background using a fullscreen quad (just like you do with your sprites, but sized to fit the entire screen).

Render this fullscreen background **first** (very important) and then also **remove** the `gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` call in from `onDrawFrame`. You no longer need to clear the color buffer because your "full screen" background image will overwrite the entire surface (essentially doing the exact same thing as clearing) - this will also provide some performance increase.

Also, make sure that you disable **ALPHA BLENDING** before rendering your background image; you can enable it **after** the background image is rendered.

Comment: Thanks, you were precise and it worked perfectly. Now I have to re-create many images, but I'm glad to have solved the problem.

Comment: Glad to help, and good luck :)